# mex -setup seems complete while during compilation i get error "no compiler installed"

Tags: matlab, installation

I am using Matlab 2012a on a W7 64-bit machine. Don't quite remember now, it was half a year ago when I installed stuff, so now I can only guess the sequence based on installation dates.

Right now I've got Matlab, Matlab compiler runtime, MS Windows SDK 7.1 and .NET Framework 4 and many other perhaps unnecessary programs (I found e.g. MS Visual C++ 2008 standard compilers). 
Recently I tried the procedure stated [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-IB1G3Q/) , to no effect. I haven't reinstalled anything yet.

I may attach list of programs with installation dates, if necessary.
The problem is as follows - even though I've completed mex -setup (and it seems it succeeded, it shows the correct path to SDK 7.1 and accepts it), during compiling a model in simulink I get an error "an installed compiler was not detected". I'd like to know what should I do now.

Comment: I spent several entire days trying to get the Matlab compiler working on Windows 7. I eventually gave up and re-installed Matlab as 32-bit, which comes with a built-in compiler and Mex seems to work out of the box.

Comment: @jerad - thanks a million, sorry for delay. As a 'getting things done' solution, it's really fast and harmless. Works like charm (so far so good)!

Comment: @jerad could you please write it as a 'work-around' answer?

Comment: sure I'll post it as answer since it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of people have this problem on Windows 7, and while Mathworks has published a solution, I spent several days trying and re-trying it to no avail.

As a work around, re-install Matlab as 32-bit. It comes with a built-in compiler, and Mex seems to work out of the box. Less than ideal but it works.